# How can I do this formula but for the entire Column in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

This is the formula I use that works for row 4,

```
=IF(E4 - D4 >= 3,C4 + 3,"IF(E4 - D4 <= -2, C4 - 2, IF(E4 - D4 > 0 And E4 - D4 < 3, C4 + E4 - D4, IF(E4 - D4 > -2 And E4 - D4 < 0,  G4 = C4 + E4 - D4, C4)))")
```

How would I get it to work for every row below row 4 also?

Comment: Just drag it down? Move curser to the bottom right corner till it changes to a solid +, left click and drag down.

Comment: Or copy/paste it to the other cells in the column. Excel will automatically adjust the row numbers.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1 - Dragging

Select the cell, click on the little square in the bottom right hand corner and drag it down (as Scott said in the comments)

### Method 2 - Double clicking

Double clicking will automatically fill the formula downwards to the end of the range containing data

Later Excel versions are a bit smarter in that regard as old ones and software packages like Google Sheets just go down to the last non-empty cell left to the cell you are dragging. (Thanks Scott)

### Method 3 - Copy-Paste

Copy and paste it (as lurker said).
It suffices to select the cell with the formula, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, select the rows of the column where you want the formula to be pasted and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

### Method 4 - CTRL + D

Keyboard shortcut version.

- Go to the end of the range you want to apply the formula to and
  select it.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

### Method 5 - Arrayformula

Select the range where you want the formula to be applied (I used `E4:E6` etc.) and use this formula:

```
=IF(E4:E6 - D4:D6 >= 3,C4:C6 + 3,"IF(E4 - D4 <= -2, C4 - 2, IF(E4 - D4 > 0 And E4 - D4 < 3, C4 + E4 - D4, IF(E4 - D4 > -2 And E4 - D4 < 0,  G4 = C4 + E4 - D4, C4)))")
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
You can apply this for the whole column if you use `E:E` but you have to start at row 1.
This will evaluate the formula and take the row of the range the formula is being executed in.
That means if you apply the formula to `F4:F6` with the formula containing `F4:F6` it will evaluate it once for every row in the range.

### Method 6 - VBA

What are you still doing here?

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("F4").Copy
    For Each Row In Range("F4:F100")
        Row.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next Row
End Sub
```

Iterates through the columns and sets the formula

### Method 7 - Writing a Python script that modifies the .xlsx

oh come on...

---

If you want to edit the row reference in the string as well you can do that easily using string concatenation replacing every `4` with `"&ROW()&"` making it:

```
=IF(E4 - D4 >= 3,C4 + 3,"IF(E"&ROW()&" - D"&ROW()&" <= -2, C"&ROW()&" - 2, IF(E"&ROW()&" - D"&ROW()&" > 0 And E"&ROW()&" - D"&ROW()&" < 3, C"&ROW()&" + E"&ROW()&" - D"&ROW()&", IF(E"&ROW()&" - D"&ROW()&" > -2 And E"&ROW()&" - D"&ROW()&" < 0,  G"&ROW()&" = C"&ROW()&" + E"&ROW()&" - D"&ROW()&", C"&ROW()&")))")
```

or for the array formula

```
=IF(E4:E6 - D4:D6 >= 3,C4:C6 + 3,"IF(E"&ROW()&" - D"&ROW()&" <= -2, C"&ROW()&" - 2, IF(E"&ROW()&" - D"&ROW()&" > 0 And E"&ROW()&" - D"&ROW()&" < 3, C"&ROW()&" + E"&ROW()&" - D"&ROW()&", IF(E"&ROW()&" - D"&ROW()&" > -2 And E"&ROW()&" - D"&ROW()&" < 0,  G"&ROW()&" = C"&ROW()&" + E"&ROW()&" - D"&ROW()&", C"&ROW()&")))")
```

Comment: One more -- Double clicking, goes with the first one, if there is data adjacent.  Other than that -- NICE.

Comment: How could I forget that. Thanks!